# Recalling values from dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, command-line

I tried writing a program that takes command line inputs (supposed to be numbers) and stores them in a dynamically allocated array, the prints them out by accessing the array. However, it's printing random values instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int *list_nums;
    list_nums = malloc(argc * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        list_nums[i-1] = argv[i];
    }
    printf("you entered: ");
    for (i = 0; i < argc-1; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", list_nums[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Originally, I had the print statement in the second for loop as:

```
        printf("%s, ", list_nums[i])  // %s instead of %d
```

since `argv[]` was set to `char` but that gives me a Segmentation Fault. What's going on here?

Comment: Why are you `malloc()`ing `sizeof(int)` when you write `char *`s to the allocated memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always pay attention to your compiler's warnings. If you aren't getting any warnings, check your compiler settings.

```
$ gcc -Wall -O a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     list_nums = malloc(argc * sizeof(int));
     ^
a.c:6:17: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
     list_nums = malloc(argc * sizeof(int));
                 ^
a.c:8:24: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
         list_nums[i-1] = argv[i];
                        ^
```

The first warning says that `malloc` isn't declared; you're missing `#include <stdlib.h>`. On most systems this won't cause an actual problem. The second warning is a consequence of the same problem.

The third warning indicates a real problem. `argv` is an array of pointers to `char`, so `argv[i]` is a pointer to `char`. `list_nums` points to an array of integers. So you're assigning a pointer to an integer. The random-looking numbers that you're printing out are the addresses of the arguments in memory.

You can copy an array of strings into an array of strings. In this case, you need to change `list_nums` to an array of `char*`, and use the `%s` specifier for printing.

It seems that you intended to interpret the arguments as integers though. If you want to convert the arguments — which are strings — to integers, you need to do that explicitly. You can use the `atoi` function for quick throwaway code, or `strtol` for robust code (`atoi` doesn't permit error checking).

```
long *list_nums = malloc((argc-1) * sizeof(*list_nums));
char *end;
if (list_nums == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    list_nums[i-1] = strtol(argv[i], &end, 0);
    if (*end != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid argument: %s\n", argv[i]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < argc-1; i++) {
    printf("%ld, ", list_nums[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that you are assigning `argv` elements to an `int` array. Since `argv` elements are C strings, you need to *parse* them to obtain `int`:

```
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    list_nums[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
}
```

Don't forget to `free(list_nums)` at the end of your program.

Include `<stdlib.h>` to use [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int *list_nums = NULL;

    if ( argc > 1 ) list_nums = malloc( ( argc - 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
        list_nums[i-1] = atoi( argv[i] );
    }

    printf("you entered: ");
    for ( i = 0; i < argc-1; i++ ) {
        printf( "%d, ", list_nums[i] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    free( list_nums );

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention that arguments are stored like character arrays. So you have to convert a string containing a number in an object of type int.